# Hosts uses Server IP address instead of its dedicated IP for outbound connections

Tags: networking

I have a cPanel installed dedicated box.
All of the hosts thats are in it have their own IP addresses.
However when I try to connect to bank's POS system, host uses server IP.
Why do hosts not use their dedicated IPs for outbound connections?

By the way, CSF firewall also installed. Do I make an arrangement via CSF IPTABLES configuration? Would it be work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `iptables`, you would set the SNAT address.  I assume that each of these "hosts" are virtual machines like in Xen, OpenVZ, KVM, etc.  You'd do something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.2 -j SNAT --to 5.0.0.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.3 -j SNAT --to 5.0.0.3
... and so on
```

The above assumes that the Internet port is eth0 and that your virtual host IP addresses are 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3 and that their public IP addresses are 5.0.0.2 and 5.0.0.3, respectively.

If your hosts are actually just virtualhosts in Apache or similar, that's a whole different ballgame.

Comment: host are not virtual machines they all located i a dedicated machine which managing by whm cpanel.
So they all vhost on apache

Answer (score 1):

Use iptables to SNAT source IP when connecting to bank's POS system.